# How to call memorystream to browser download?

Tags: javascript, pdf, browser, download

I have the following controller action:

```
   var fileName = "monthly_report.pdf"
    var document = new Document();
    //DO SOME STUFF WITH THE DOCUMENT

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    doc.Save(stream, SaveFormat.Pdf);
    byte[] bytes = stream.GetBuffer();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+fileName);
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.End();
```

I want to call the above controller action with a parameter date so it returns me a pdf file that can be downloaded in the browser.

While it already is being returned in the response it displays lots of unreadable signs and i cannot get the file download to start doin it via an ajax call ( which i know now doesn work ).

The question is: how do i call a controller action from javascript with a javascript var as parameter with an action that is not an ajax call?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 0):

Very simple !

Use :

```
window.open("http://url_of_your_pdf_built_in_function?vars=something&etc=something");
```

Regards